# Kafka 1.0 : Alter number of partitions for a specific topic using java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

The AdminUtils.addPartition call in Kafka 1.0 appears to have changed the signature as shown below from the 2 version - 0.10.2.0 vs 1.0.0

==========================

## Kafka 0.10.2.0

```
/**
  * Add partitions to existing topic with optional replica assignment
  *
  * @param zkUtils Zookeeper utilities
  * @param topic Topic for adding partitions to
  * @param numPartitions Number of partitions to be set
  * @param replicaAssignmentStr Manual replica assignment
  * @param checkBrokerAvailable Ignore checking if assigned replica broker             is available. Only used for testing
   */
   def addPartitions(zkUtils: ZkUtils,
                     topic: String,
                     numPartitions: Int = 1,
                     replicaAssignmentStr: String = "",
                     checkBrokerAvailable: Boolean = true,
                     rackAwareMode: RackAwareMode = RackAwareMode.Enforced)
```

==========================

## Kafka 1.0.0

```
 /**
   * Add partitions to existing topic with optional replica assignment
   *
   * @param zkUtils Zookeeper utilities
   * @param topic Topic for adding partitions to
   * @param existingAssignment A map from partition id to its assigned      replicas
   * @param allBrokers All brokers in the cluster
   * @param numPartitions Number of partitions to be set
   * @param replicaAssignment Manual replica assignment, or none
   * @param validateOnly If true, validate the parameters without actually      adding the partitions
   * @return the updated replica assignment
   */
   def addPartitions(zkUtils: ZkUtils,
                     topic: String,
                     existingAssignment: Map[Int, Seq[Int]],
                     allBrokers: Seq[BrokerMetadata],
                     numPartitions: Int = 1,
                     replicaAssignment: Option[Map[Int, Seq[Int]]] = None,
                     validateOnly: Boolean = false): Map[Int, Seq[Int]] =
```

Any ideas on how we can use the new addPartitions call in Java easily without having to specify the existing and new replica assigments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Munish - Thank you for the response. Here is the code which worked for me.

```
Seq<String> names = JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList(topicName));

Seq<BrokerMetadata> brokers = AdminUtils.getBrokerMetadatas(zkUtils,RackAwareMode.Enforced$.MODULE$, Option.empty());

scala.collection.mutable.Map<String, scala.collection.Map<Object, Seq<Object>>> assignment = (scala.collection.mutable.Map<String,     scala.collection.Map<Object, Seq<Object>>>)zkUtils.getPartitionAssignmentForTopics(names);

Map<String, scala.collection.Map<Object, Seq<Object>>> partitionaAssigmentMap = JavaConverters.mutableMapAsJavaMap(assignment);

AdminUtils.addPartitions(zkUtils, topicName, partitionaAssigmentMap.get(topicName), brokers,partitionCount, Option.empty(), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Its working for me

```
Seq<String> names = JavaConverters.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList(topicname)).toSeq();
        Seq<BrokerMetadata> brokers = AdminUtils.getBrokerMetadatas(zkUtils, Enforced$.MODULE$, Option.empty());

        Map<String, Map<Object, Seq<Object>>> assignment
            = zkUtils.getPartitionAssignmentForTopics(names);
        Option<Map<Object, Seq<Object>>> assgn = assignment.get(topicname);

        AdminUtils.addPartitions(zkUtils, topicname, assgn.get(), brokers, partitions, Option.empty(), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

From 1.0.0 you can use kafka clients library instead

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version> <!-- or newer -->
</dependency>
```

In java code it will look like:

```
NewPartition newPartitionRequest = NewPartitions.increaseTo(10);
client.createPartitions(Collections.singletonMap("topicName", newPartitionRequest)).all().get();  //kafka clients AdminClient
```